# Seeing user information for main site and meta

Tags: support, inbox

Is there any way of seeing whether I have responses in either main or meta, without having to open up two different user pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Responses specific to you across *all* StackExchange networks is usually available from [your StackExchange Inbox](http://stackexchange.com/users/1700887/mohan?tab=inbox). This includes responses to your comments, comments to your questions/answers (even if their not directed at you), chats or answers in general.

For user `MyUser` (number `1234567`), the address is

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/1234567/MyUser?tab=inbox
```

or accessible by clicking on the StackExchange drop-down menu in the top left of the browser and selecting Inbox.